# Run bat file as administrator but shown on user's profile

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, remote-access, administrator

I wrote this script to run a file remotely on another computer, however I would like to run it as an administrator user but for it to be shown on the user's computer. How do I run a script as administrator remotely but to show it on the user's profile?

```
@echo off

color 0a

SET /p ComputerName=ComputerName:

SET /p UserName=Please enter the username:

SET /p UserNamePassword=Please enter Username Password:

 tasklist /s \\%ComputerName% /u %UserName% /p %UserNamePassword% /FI "memusage gt 200000"

SET /p Value=would you like to continue? Press 1 if yes.Press 2 to exit:


IF %Value% EQU 1  pushd \\NetworkPath & copy batfile.bat \\%ComputerName%\c$\Users\%UserName%\Desktop & popd & psexec -i -s -d \\%ComputerName% -u %UserName% -p %UserNamePassword% "C:\Users\%UserName%\Desktop\batfile.bat"
IF %Value% EQU 2 exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the command line `nircmd elevate "the path of your program.bat"` to start the program. Or you could create another .bat file reading this:

```
nircmd elevate "the path of your program.bat"
exit
```

To open your main program, just open this second .bat program and it will open your main program as the administrator and then close itself out.

Nircmd is not a default windows command. You would have to download it from [this website](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/elevate.html) by clicking on the "Download NirCmd" button on the bottom of the webpage. Choose to save this .zip file, and when it is done, extract it. Then only copy the file "nircmd.exe" into your "system32" directory or %systemroot%. Now nircmd is part of the commands you can use in "cmd.exe".

I have nircmd on my computer, if you have trouble trusting it. It is a very useful tool to have. The above link also has a list of all of the functions and their descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this to make a batch-file run as admin:

```
SET ADMIN=0
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (GOTO askAdmin)
SET ADMIN=1
GOTO gotAdmin
:askAdmin
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )
:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B
:gotAdmin
if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
```

Put that at the top of your batch-file